# Sorting files numerically, including negative numbers

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a bunch of files:

```
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+0,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-10,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+10,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-15,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+15,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-20,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+20,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-25,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+25,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-30,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+30,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-5,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+5,00.pdb
```

I would like to sort numerically to get the following:

```
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-30,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-25,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-20,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-15,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-10,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-5,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+0,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+5,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+10,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+15,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+20,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+25,00.pdb
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A+30,00.pdb
```

Is there a sort command to do this? So far, I have the following:

```
for i in $(ls *.pdb | sort -V); do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

```
ls *.pdb | sort -k 1.20g
```

(Yes, I know [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and more; see pitfalls section below).

---

#### Sorting logic

A general numeric sort (`sort -g`) is the one you want, but you should specify where numbers start.

Your examples are of the form:

```
adenine-N1_B+1,70_A-15,00.pdb
                   ^ the number starts here: character 20, always
```

There are no blanks, so plain `sort` considers the entire filename to be just one field. You need a general numeric sort that works from the 20th character of the 1st field:

```
sort -k 1.20g
```

You may want to introduce more complex logic to this. E.g. if one of the entries was `bogonine-X3_B+1,00_A-12,00.pdb`, it would be quite sane to decompose entries like this:

```
foo_bar_A+00,00.pdb
   ^   ^ field separators
^ first field starts here
        ^ third field starts here
         ^ the number starts here: field 3, character 2
```

and to sort (e.g.) according to the first field, then by these numbers, like this:

```
sort -t '_' -k 1,1 -k 3.2g
```

(Compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709427)).

---

#### Locale

The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. One can encounter advice to set `LC_ALL=C` just in case. This may or may not be what you want, depending on whether you want to treat the last comma (`,`) as a decimal separator or not (well, you have `,00` in every entry, so it shouldn't really matter; but it does matter in general).

If you need to change the locale just for one particular invocation of `sort`, this is the way:

```
LC_ALL=C sort …
```

---

#### Pitfalls in various approaches

This is what you have tried:

> ```
> for i in $(ls *.pdb | sort -V); do echo $i; done
> ```

The command is overly complicated, the inner part does basically the same job:

```
ls *.pdb | sort -V
```

Parsing the output of `ls` is [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), although your example filenames are quite safe, so you should get away with it. Note you don't need `ls` at all:

```
for i in *.pdb; do echo "$i"; done | sort …
```

The problem with `ls *.pdb` is you may hit the `argument list too long` error (well, not in your example case, but again: in general). The syntax `for i in *.pdb; …` is immune.

Your example names seem safe to be used with `echo` as well ([see the general problem with `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)). They don't contain special characters so you don't need `find … -print0` nor `sort -z …` etc.